# Apple Developer Account - Sharing credentials

Tags: ios, credentials, apple-developer

I am working with a developer Team in abroad (other country), basically they are handling one of my projects for me.

The projects has a in-app purchase option, and the developer team in India has asked me to share the credentials of my apple developer account in order to integrate that function.

I am not so aware of how that works, but what should I do now - meaning is it safe to share my credentials?

Do I basically need to share my login and password details or what should I do?

Comment: You NEVER share login credentials, **NEVER**.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: @luk2302 What is the option here then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an Apple Developer Account with a team/organization entity type and then add them as team Members *not* team Admins and remove them when you're done. If you don't have a team account and you don't want to migrate your individual account to a team account for whatever reason, then the only way I can think of achieving what you want is to manually create the permissions you need, then use Fastlane to store certs and provisioning remotely on a private repo, and provide read-only access to those files via custom lanes using Match so they don't even need access to your dev account.